# Flutter Bottom over flowed by pixels, tried Column(), Row(), Container() and many many more things

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

Flutter Bottom overflowed by pixels, tried Column(), Row(), Container() and many many more things but nothing helped me to solve my problem. I'm sharing the complete code here, please take a look.

Please help me if anyone understands where is the issue.

Flutter Bottom overflowed by pixels, tried Column(), Row(), Container() and many many more things but nothing helped me to solve my problem. I'm sharing the complete code here, please take a look.

Please help me if anyone understands where is the issue.

````
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:app_settings/app_settings.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:giffy_dialog/giffy_dialog.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:url_flutter_app/screens/Dash_board.dart';
import 'package:url_flutter_app/screens/Search.dart';
import 'package:unicorndial/unicorndial.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/home1';
  @override
  DashboardState createState() => new DashboardState();
}

class DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {

  StreamSubscription connectivitySubscription;
  ConnectivityResult _previousResult;

  bool dialogshown = false;

  Future<bool> checkinternet() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        return Future.value(true);
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    connectivitySubscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult connresult) {
      if (connresult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        dialogshown = true;

        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => AssetGiffyDialog(
                  image: Image.asset(
                    'assets/1fqC.gif',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'Error',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                  entryAnimation: EntryAnimation.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
                  description: Text(
                    "No Internet Detected, Please Enable your Internet Connection and try again. Thank You. \n"
                        "Press 'OK' to turn on your mobile data or WiFi connection, or press 'Cancel' to exit the app.",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  onOkButtonPressed: () {
                    //_onAlertButtonsPressed(context);
                    AppSettings.openDeviceSettings();
                  },
                  onCancelButtonPressed: (){
                    SystemNavigator.pop(); //for Android from flutter/services.dart
                    exit(0);
                  },
                ),
        );

        } else if (_previousResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        checkinternet().then((result) {
          if (result == true) {
            if (dialogshown == true) {
              dialogshown = false;
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          }
        });
      }

      _previousResult = connresult;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    connectivitySubscription.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var floatingButtons = List<UnicornButton>();
    floatingButtons.add(
      UnicornButton(
        hasLabel: true,
        labelText: "Search Map",
        currentButton: FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: "Search Map",
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          mini: true,
          child: Icon(Icons.search_rounded),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Search()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
    floatingButtons.add(
      UnicornButton(
        hasLabel: true,
        labelText: "Facebook Page",
        currentButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _facebook,
          heroTag: "facebook",
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          mini: true,
          child: Icon(Icons.facebook),
        ),
      ),
    );
    floatingButtons.add(
      UnicornButton(
        hasLabel: true,
        labelText: "Our Website",
        currentButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _website,
          heroTag: "website",
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          mini: true,
          child: Icon(Icons.open_in_browser),
        ),
      ),
    );
    floatingButtons.add(
      UnicornButton(
        hasLabel: true,
        labelText: "Whatsapp us",
        currentButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _whatsapp,
          heroTag: "whatsapp",
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          mini: true,
          child: Icon(Icons.whatshot),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: UnicornDialer(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
          parentButtonBackground: Colors.deepPurple,
          orientation: UnicornOrientation.VERTICAL,
          parentButton: Icon(Icons.message_outlined),
          childButtons: floatingButtons),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 110,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "  ColorLine",
                      style: GoogleFonts.breeSerif(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black87,
                              fontSize: 36,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "    Maps",
                      style: GoogleFonts.breeSerif(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff000000),
                              fontSize: 24,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 110,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    "assets/Final_Logo.png",
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          GridDashboard()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

_whatsapp() async {
  const url = 'https://wa.me/16694002123';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

_facebook() async {
  const url = 'https://www.facebook.com/colorline7007/';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

_website() async {
  const url = 'https://colorline.pk';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
} ```
````

Comment: Go here my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView` or replace it by a `ListView`.

Your view overflows because it isn't scrollable and doesn't have enough space to render the content.

Comment: Already tried this, can you run it in your system?

Comment: No, not there. You need to wrap your `Column` with _just_ a `SingleChildScrollView` not both.

Comment: Well, it's not a column it's a "ShowDialog()".

Comment: How can I wrap a "ShowDialog"?

Comment: You need to wrap the inner column. You can’t wrap the showDialog, since it’s a modal render in an overlay.

Comment: I'm still stuck here :(