# Flutter Web inconsistent line height

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Here are two screenshots taken on mobile phone chrome browser and pc chrome browser, both are the exact same site. Things look fine on pc chrome browser, but lines of text are all disoriented on mobile phone chrome browser.

Note: I am using TextStyle.height in most Text widgets.

Is there any solution to this issue?

[image: screenshot taken on mobile phone chrome browser]

[image: screenshot taken on pc chrome browser]

Comment: Refer My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210) hope its help to you.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the solution on my own.

Select canvaskit as web renderer when running flutter build web.

```
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```

Refer [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers),

> auto (default) - automatically chooses which renderer to use. This option chooses the HTML renderer when the app is running in a mobile browser, and CanvasKit renderer when the app is running in a desktop browser.

> html - always use the HTML renderer.

> canvaskit - always use the CanvasKit renderer.

Since the unwanted overlapping behaviour is showing up in mobile browser, I forced the build to canvaskit.

Comment: This is no longer the case. (soon to hit stable) https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/platform-views-using-html-slots-web