# Listview.build does not scroll on Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I only tried this on Dartpad, and the Listview does not scroll! I based the code out on https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists.

My original intention is testing for horizontal scroll, but then I find out that it does not scroll vertically either!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(
      items: List<String>.generate(100, (i) => 'Item $i'),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Long List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(items[index]),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add your Widgets inside `SingleChildScrollView` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: add `MaterialApp(
scrollBehavior: MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
dragDevices: {PointerDeviceKind.mouse},
),`

Comment: @pskink It works! Thank you. Does this change anything for users who use the web app on phone?

Comment: Apparently enable dragDevices for mouse disable dragging on phone, when user run web app on phone. It's also not recommended https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollBehavior/dragDevices.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap with Scrollbar

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(
      items: List<String>.generate(100, (i) => 'Item $i'),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Long List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: Scrollbar(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(items[index]),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works with a ScrollController is set to both Scrollbar and ListView.builder

Answer (score 4):

Simply add scroll Behavior in the Material App in main.dart
Add these lines.

```
  scrollBehavior: MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
    dragDevices: {PointerDeviceKind.mouse, PointerDeviceKind.touch, PointerDeviceKind.stylus, PointerDeviceKind.unknown},
  ),
```

and import gestures package. Your web scroll will work fine