# A RenderFlex overflowed bottom flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

when I run the project it shows A RenderFlex overflowed on the bottom
[image]
A RenderFlex overflowed by 6.7 pixels on the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

In your Scaffold, set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property to false.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. add your `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView`

Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210) also

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   child:Column(
     children:[
      //Declare Your Widgets Here
     ],
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

When the kayboard appears, it may hide something.
To avoid this problem, you can wrap the entire screen widget in a `SingleChildScrollView`. This will mate the screen scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to block the widgets inside the Scaffold to resize themselves when the keyboard opens but this way,

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Expenses Tracker'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView( // wrap with a scrollable widget
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...... // other widgets 
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```