# Fixing error Bottom OverFlowed By in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gridview

I'm working on a flutter project and it's been hours I can't solve this error. I made a GridView which titles are outside the card but I have this error. I can't put height upper than 56. I want to make them look like squares. Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

this is my code :

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = true;
            });
            _splitScreen2(index);
          },
        child: Card(
          elevation: 18.0,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
    child: Expanded(
          child: Image.asset(
            img,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
           
          ),
    ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        ),
    ),
        Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Try to add your `Column()` inside `SingleChildScrollView()` widget refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210)

Comment: Is there another solution because I can't see the title until I scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before**(Your Code)
[image]

```
Container(
      // height: 150,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              // setState(() {
              //   isLoading = true;
              // });
              // _splitScreen2(index);
            },
            child: Card(
              elevation: 18.0,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
              child: Expanded(
                child: Image.Network(
                  data["Image"],
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,

                ),
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            data["name"],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**After**
[image]

```
Container(
      // height: 150,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          // setState(() {
          //   isLoading = true;
          // });
          // _splitScreen2(index);
        },
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                    data["Image"],
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                data["Name"],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Consider `Column` as a Child widget of `Card`

```
class ItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  var data;

  ItemWidget(this.data, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var column = Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            // height: 125,
            child: Image.network(
              data["Image"],
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
            child: Text(
          data["Name"],
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        ))
      ],
    );
    var column2 = InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        // setState(() {
        //   isLoading = true;
        // });
        // _splitScreen2(index);
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Image.network(
                data["Image"],
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            data["Name"],
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12.0,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
    return Container(
      // height: 150,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          // setState(() {
          //   isLoading = true;
          // });
          // _splitScreen2(index);
        },
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                    data["Image"],
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                data["Name"],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```