# How to set width of Slidable widget?

Tags: flutter

I have to do Slidable widget with 3 CustomSlidableAction. I did it, but Slidable is open only to half of child widget and I don't have enough space for CustomSlidableActions. How can I open Slidable more than half of child width?

I've tried to google, but I  didn't find the answer. If you know how to do it or have some links to read more about Slidable - please share

Here is the full code:

```
    class SlidableWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const SlidableWrapper({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slidable(
      endActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const ScrollMotion(),
        children: [
          CustomSlidableAction(
            onPressed: (_) {
              //make messages unread
            },
            backgroundColor: Palette.green,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 24.w,
              vertical: 11.h,
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25.h,
                  width: 25.w,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/Chats.svg',
                    color: Palette.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6.h,
                ),
                Text(
                  'unread'.tr(),
                  style: TextStyles.poppins14400.copyWith(
                    color: Palette.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          CustomSlidableAction(
            onPressed: (_) {
              //pin chat
            },
            backgroundColor: Palette.green,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 24.w,
              vertical: 11.h,
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25.h,
                  width: 25.w,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/pin.svg',
                    color: Palette.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6.h,
                ),
                Text(
                  'pin'.tr(),
                  style: TextStyles.poppins14400.copyWith(
                    color: Palette.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          CustomSlidableAction(
            onPressed: (_) {
              //more actions
            },
            backgroundColor: Palette.green,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 24.w,
              vertical: 11.h,
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25.h,
                  width: 25.w,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/more.svg',
                    color: Palette.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6.h,
                ),
                Text(
                  'more'.tr(),
                  style: TextStyles.poppins14400.copyWith(
                    color: Palette.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the problem:
[image]

Comment: Wrap your `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView` refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210) answer

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil it gives me the opportunity to scroll the column, but I don't need it. I want to take more space in width to my CustomSlidableActions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use extentRatio parameter in ActionPane

```
 endActionPane: ActionPane(
    motion: const ScrollMotion(),
    extentRatio: 0.5, //This is a percentage of the width
    children: [...]),
```