# RenderBox was not laid out with Image.network

Tags: flutter

[image]

https://github.com/kangsudal/my_openweather_map/blob/6f5a581eeb76417566a0f4135106aeddc7ce736a/lib/bottom.dart#L64

CellWidget is Column under Title.
It says overflow.
I used Expanded, boxfit.
But it is not solved.
I guess it is because of Image.network.

help me please.

Comment: Wrap your **CellWidget** `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView` refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210)

Comment: Inside CellWidget builder,
return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          FittedBox(

I added SingleChildScrollView instead of Expanded. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
class CellWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  CellWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.date,
    required this.icon,
    required this.celcious,
  }) : super(key: key);
  String date;
  Image icon;
  String celcious;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child:Column(
      children: [
        FittedBox(
          child: Text(date),
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        ),
        FittedBox(
          child: icon,
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        ),
        FittedBox(
          child: Text('$celcious°'),
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        ),
      ], 
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I did SingleChildScrollView instead of Expanded. Still it say overflowed.