# How to clip overflowing column widget contained by stack contained by column

Tags: flutter, dart

**There are two main widgets:**

I have this `OverflowingWidget` that is basically a `Column` - in reality this contains many widgets - However for this example, it has been given a height bigger than its parent widget.

The Parent widget `ContainerWidget` is basically `AnimatedSwitcher` which is basically a `Stack` contained by `Column` which constrained by a hight less than `OverflowingWidget`.
As you can see in [dart-pad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=46765b328c3ac8c8be7409dc26d4ead6) there is an overflow. The `OverflowingWidget`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ContainerWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ContainerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 100,
        width: 50,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ClipRect(
                child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    child: OverflowingWidget(),
                    layoutBuilder: (currentChild, previousChildren) => Stack(
                          children: [
                            ...previousChildren,
                            if (currentChild != null) currentChild,
                          ],
                        )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}


class OverflowingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: [Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 150, width: 50)]);
  }
}
```

**Desired result:**

I need the `OverflowingWidget` to be clean clipped without trying to resize the content inside. The same effect that can be obtained when in `css`:`overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Put your `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210) and remove your `Expanded` widget above of thr `Cliprect`

Comment: Thank you but I just need it to be clipped not scrollable. There must be a way to clip a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to clip an overflowing column/row. Simply wrap that column/row with `Wrap` widget. That will do the clipping.

```dart
class OverflowingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(children: [
      Column(children: [
        Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 150,
            width: 50)
      ])
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`AnimatedSwitcher` is getting height 100, but it needs 150 for current widget. you can increase the height on redContainer.

Instead of using Column, you can use Stack widget.

```dart
class ContainerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 150,
        width: 50,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            ClipRect(
              child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  child: OverflowingWidget(),
                  layoutBuilder: (currentChild, previousChildren) => Stack(
                        children: [
                          ...previousChildren,
                          if (currentChild != null) currentChild,
                        ],
                      )),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The height is a constraint that cannot be changed. Why would I make it smaller if it doesn’t serve any purpose and consequently it gives me this issue of overflow. There has to be a column there as in reality it contains other widgets stacked vertically.